# Missing signature, uploader from createPresignedPost from aws-sdk-js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, aws-sdk

Missing signature, uploader from createPresignedPost from aws-sdk with the below code. Not getting the relevant result to upload file to s3 as per the [react-dropzone-uploader](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/s3#s3-using-put-instead-of-post). While uploading file facing 403 error from aws s3

```
 const params = {
      Bucket: myBucket,
      Key: myKey,
      Fields: {
        Key: myKey,
        AWSAccessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        acl: "public-read",
      },
      Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
      Conditions: [
          ['content-length-range', 0, 100000000], // 100 Mb
          {'acl': 'public-read'}
      ]
  };
    s3.createPresignedPost(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Presigning post data encountered an error', err);
      } else {
        // console.log('The post data is', data);

         data.fileUrl = data.url+"/"+data.fields.key;
         data.uploadUrl = data.url+"/";
          res.status(200).send(
            new apiResponse.responseObject(200, data, null).getResObject()
          );
      }
    });
```

https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/s3#s3-using-put-instead-of-post

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass AWSAccessKeyId inside the params when generating the presigned URL. Also the 'acl' should be outside the Fields property.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
        Bucket: myBucket,
        Fields: {
            key: myKey
        },
        Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
        Conditions: [
            ['content-length-range', 0, 10000000], // 10 Mb
            {'acl': 'public-read'}
        ]
    };
    s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
        resolve(data);
    });
});
```